# How does inject handle the first element of an array when summing?

Tags: ruby, arrays, inject

I have:

```
arr=[40, 50, 60, 70]

arr.inject do |sum,x|
  p x
  p sum
  if x>50
    sum=sum+x
  end
  p sum
end
```

Why does `x` start on 50 and `sum` start on 40? My guess would be that `x` would iterate over 40 first.  Better yet, how do I make this statement, using the `inject` method, return 130?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject is using the first element of the array as a starting sum and executes the block starting from the second element. You can pass a starting sum to inject using `inject(0) do ..end`.
It will then start with `sum` equal to 0 and execute the block from first the element. Also note that `sum` is being assigned to the value of the executed block, so your code won't work at all. It should be:

```
arr=[40, 50, 60, 70]

arr.inject do |sum,x|
  x > 50 ? sum+x : sum
end
```

However I would write it slightly simpler:

```
arr=[40, 50, 60, 70]

arr.select {|v| v > 50}.reduce(0, &:+)
```

If you are using Active Support (from Rails), you can simply do:

```
arr.select {|v| v > 50}.sum
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I didn't have it quite as short as yours, but I wrote it out while experimenting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't supply an argument to the `inject` method, the value of `sum` will be the value of the first element in an array. If you want it to be 100, start your code with `arr.inject(100)`.